# How to make a half second cooldown for weapon attacks in a video game in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make a cooldown for an attack. Right now you can spam it and can swing as fast as you can click but I would like to balance the game better and add a small cooldown. I cant seem to find how to do this anywhere though. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service. [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ibrahim Matar Post these kind of things on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use IEnumerator function which contains something like this:

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float cooldownTime;
    private bool isCooldown;

    // your code

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isCooldown)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Cooldown()
    {
        // Start cooldown
        isCooldown = true;
        // Wait for time you want
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldownTime);
        // Stop cooldown
        isCooldown = false;
    }
}
```

Just start coroutine in attack handler

Answer (score 1):

You would want something along the lines of the following. Since I don't have any of your code, I'll assume this is under a player class and will write accordingly.

```
class PlayerClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer = 0.0f;
    float cooldownTime = 1.0f;

    void Update() {
        if(timer > cooldownTime) { 
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                Attack();
                timer = 0;
            }
        }

        if(timer < cooldownTime + 1) // Add some leaniency for inaccurate floating points.
            timer += time.DeltaTime;
    }
}
```

Obviously, try this code. I'm at work right now and don't have access to my PC so you'll need to deal with untested C#! And of course, do some googling on timers and stuff like that, because that will be where you need to look. Also look into IEnumerable for asynchronous code if you're looking to get fancy.

(>^3^)>